# Force Serializable attribute on undefined type

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, attributes, custom-attributes

I'd like to make something like a list of objects implementing interface:

```
public List<ISerializable> objectsToSerialize;
```

except that serializable types just have `[Serializable]` attribute, and not implement the `ISerializable` interface. So what I need is something like:

```
public List<[Serializable]object> objectsToSerialize;
```

but there is no such thing in C#.

I searched the web and SO but have not found any solution to force assigning to the list only objects with a specified attribute. Is it possible?

I can't force all the serialized objects to implement the `ISerializable` as this is kind of utility tool and I do not have access to the objects serialized.

Comment: You're right you can't do that. You can wrap this list into another object that checks in `Add` that the item supports `ISerializable` or has the attribute. If you use an [ObservableCollection<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a list you can register an event that does the check.

Comment: Thanks @Verarind, yes I can check it at runtime, though I was hoping for a compile-time solution. Guess that's not an option. Could that someone who down voted the question explain their reasons? All of my questions get down voted in the first 10 minutes and I'd like to know why.

Comment: Sorry but I think there's no compile-time check available. How should it work? Maybe you've a compiletime-unknown assembly that's loaded at runtime. How can the compiler know about this assembly and how could it decide which operations are valid? Sorry but I think there is no way to check for metadata at compile time.

Comment: Once again thank You @Verarind, since it would seem that no new answers will show, please make Your comment an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: No. Maybe someone has an answer. Maybe I don't know all about C#.